# What does "ninny-pinny" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence in Surely You're Joking Mr. Feynman:

There are all kinds of ninny-pinny, dopey things, like "it might be a good idea to try a date for the combination, because lots of people like to use dates."

What does ninny-pinny mean? I googled it but I only got the definition of ninny: a foolish or stupid person.

Comment: It might be a play on [*nincompoop*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nincompoop): a silly or stupid person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the term, and I can find no obvious definition online. But one can find a few uses of the term, and enough cases where "Ninny-Pinny" is used as a user ID to suggest that it's familiar to some group of people.

Some of the uses:

[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=llfWnDy2bqgC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=%22ninny-pinny%22&source=bl&ots=P752lFMr2b&sig=-ToJOn7eJ7-TqT0CMsvyZ-qSpl4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTpKqBmu3PAhUHllQKHaz9BMo4ChDoAQg_MAo#v=onepage&q=%22ninny-pinny%22&f=false) *Ah, to be able to bring a pause to this whole mess, to the ninny-pinny men giving useless advice, to the bad news (to the endless briefings on the state of the economy and the ever-worstening crime in the streets).*

[2](http://archiveofourown.org/works/33976) *"O Jo! how can you be such a ninny-pinny?"*

(It should be noted that the above *appears* to be a quote from Alcott's *Little Women*, though I cannot locate the corresponding passage in the Google Books copy.)

[3](http://becomingsalinger.blogspot.com/2011/04/writing-style.html) *At times, I feel a desperate need to write, but I fear that what I want to write most is from personal experience.  Things that may scrape so close to the bone as to be painful to those I know and love and have no desire to wound.  (And YES, I know that last sentence was a fragment, brain.  Stop being a ninny pinny.)  (Oh, for goodness' sake, now I'm looking up ninny pinny.  I give up on me.)*

The evidence suggests that the term is basically a sort of "rhyming slang" version of "ninny", which has already been defined above as a "foolish or stupid person".  Very likely the appearance in Alcott's book (if indeed it did) gave what would have been a nonce term "legs" among the audience of Alcott's admirers.